# Draw square with rounded corners

Tags: android, canvas, draw

I am able to draw a rect with sharp edges, now I need to make the sharp edges to rounded.

How to do that?

This is my code:

```
 public void drawShape(Canvas canvas, Renderer renderer, float x, float y,
      int seriesIndex, Paint paint) {
    float halfShapeWidth = shape_width / 2;
    canvas.drawRect(x , y - halfShapeWidth, x + SHAPE_WIDTH, y + halfShapeWidth, paint);
   }
```

How to make this rounded rect by passing the same parameters?

Answer (score 27):

Ok i solved it myself by using this code:

```
RectF r = new RectF(1,2,3,4);
canvas.drawRoundRect(r, 0, 0, mPaint);
```

Hope it will help others.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [drawRoundRect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawRoundRect%28android.graphics.RectF,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29)

You will need to pack the position and the dimensions in a RectF before you can call this function.

Answer (score -5):

```
public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final int color = 0xff424242;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
        final float roundPx = pixels;

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
    }
```